# Change List Colour according to date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, textcolor

I have a DataList which I am binding on load, which works perfectly fine. My question is how do I make this to show records that don't have a date in database, in different text colour? here is my code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlS" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /><br />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

---

```
Guid ID = (Guid)Session["ID"];

lstL = Manager.Get_ByID(ID);

if (lstLetters != null)
{
   dlS.DataSource = lstL;
   dlS.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really mean by "records that don't have a date in database",
but if it means that those records have NULL value as date then you can rewrite the Label as below:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' ForeColor='<%# Eval("DateValue") == System.DBNull ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : System.Drawing.Color.Blue %>' />
```

Comment: tried this but it doesnt work...just gives me blank screen with no list at all

Comment: OK, can you edit your post and give us two records of the table you are binding, one record which has date and another which doesn't !?

Comment: and did you just copy/paste above code, or you replaced the "DateValue" with your date column name?